# How to toggle list element through DOM Events in Javascript

Tags: javascript, list, dom, toggle

I have a list containing three elements inside a . I'm trying to toggle on and off a CSS class which strikes the text when the list element is clicked. I've created a function and used a for loop to check for the array index of the list element that was clicked.

I've defined the following:

List Items:

```
<ul>
        <li class="items line-through">Watch</li>
        <li class="items line-through">Shoes</li>
        <li class="items line-through">Cake</li>
</ul>
```

`var list = document.getElementsByClassName("line-through");`

Created a function to toggle the array element from the list based on the index when "click" event happens

```
function checkItem(index) {
    console.log("event = " + index)
    list[index].classList.toggle("line-through");
    console.log("list = " + index);}

for (var i = 0; i <= list.length; i++) {
    console.log("i= " + i);
    list[i].addEventListener("click", checkItem(i));}
```

So after my logic I've declared the for and i index with a value of zero, which is the value of the first list in the array. Then I've added the prints to check if it runs and then checked if list 0, 1, or 2 was clicked. If yes, run function and toggle list[i]. If not, i++ and verify the next one.

The problem is that now it immediately adds the toggle to the first and last items from the list. I've also tried to use `querySelectorAll("li")` but then it says that list[i] is undefined, which I do not understand why, cause when verifying list[0] in the console it present the first element.

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor your code and use the `this` keyword to target the clicked element, like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Execute the code after the HTML content is loaded
  
  const myList = document.querySelector('.my-list');
  const listElements = Array.from(myList.children);
  
  listElements.forEach( li => {
    li.addEventListener('click', checkItem);
  });
  
  function checkItem() {
    // The `this` keyword is the clicked element
    this.classList.toggle('line-through');
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="my-list">
        <li class="items line-through">Watch</li>
        <li class="items line-through">Shoes</li>
        <li class="items line-through">Cake</li>
</ul>
```

This will add the event listener to all the children elements of the list and toggle the `line-through` class on the clicked one.

Keep in mind that when manipulating the DOM, you should wrap your JS code inside a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener to prevent selecting elements that are not yet present on the page.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I've managed to make it run, didn't know about 'DOMContentLoaded'. Instead of array.from couldn't I use "getElementbyClassName("line-through") which would return the HTML Collection of the list, which contains the array? Don't really understand why it doesn't work like this.

Comment: HTML collections are not meant to be used for DOM Manipulation, they are iterable like arrays but their core is substantially different. 
This may clarify:
https://dev.to/isabelxklee/how-to-loop-through-an-htmlcollection-379k
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/htmlcollection-for-loop/